# Parse-server cloud code function 'Cannot POST'

Tags: curl, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

Most parts of my migration to open source parse-server are successful, with my data correctly stored, accessible.

I am however having problems with cloud code, specifically with running simple curl tests.

The initial parse-server installation includes a sample main.js file that contains a hello world function

My own parse installation is hosted at '/parse' so URLs use this as the root

The following is a simple request test

```
 curl -X POST \   
 -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \   
 -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:myRESTKey" \   
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \   
 -d '{}' \  
 http://localhost:1337/parse/1/functions/hello
```

The response I get is

> Cannot POST /parse/1/functions/hello

Which I take to be curls perfunctory statement that it cannot find a suitable POST endpoint

What is going wrong here?  I have simply changed the sample curl example from  Parse.com's documentation on using cloud-code to use my parse-server installation details

Comment: The `Cannot POST /parse/1/functions/hello` looks like a response from the server, not something curl said. Possibly adding -v to the command line helps you with some more clues. (and the "-X POST" part should be removed)

Comment: Yes, correct the message is a response from the server that an end point cannot be found. The answer works as described

Comment: how do I make the parse client js sdk make the calls without the /1?

Answer (score 14):

The answer is that unlike with Parses hosted solution the API version path is not something hosted with parse-server

if you host parse at e.g.:  /parse as I have done above, then that is the relative URL where the functions API is available.  So simply remove the /1/ from the path

The same curl command works with this URL

http://localhost:1337/parse/functions/hello

eg:

```
curl -X POST \   
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \   
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:myRESTKey" \   
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \   
-d '{}' \  
http://localhost:1337/parse/functions/hello
```

Comment: Great solution. Saved a lot of time too! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I applied the "hello post" logic below to run a function that is defined in Parse Open Source cloud code in main.js hosted on heroku.  I am trying to replace a former job that ran on parse.com.  Started with Curl to try and be able to run function at will.

error: 
 Cannot GET /parse/functions/sendOutboundProgressReport
STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x6000578c0; line 1981 (connection #2)
multi_done
Curl_http_done: called premature ==0
Connection #2 to host test-fake-app.herokuapp.com left intact
Expire cleared

---

curl -v POST \

-H 'X-Parse-Application-Id: sadf435hsdgfatea' \
 -H 'X-Parse-Master-Key: asdfsaasdfae4235dsgd' \
 -H 'REST_KEY': asdfasq435636 \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "X-Parse-Url: http://test-fake-app.herokuapp.com/parse" \

-d @send-template.json \

http://test-fake-app.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/sendOutboundProgressReport