# Booted off Parse.com - Why does cURL POST to parse-server work locally but not on Heroku?

Tags: curl, heroku, mlab, parse-server

Running the stock parse-server (ps) example locally and remotely on Heroku works.
Authenticating from cURL into the ps example with my cloud code (my app) works locally and remotely on Heroku.

- cURL POST to local ps + local mongodb works
- cURL GET to local ps + local mongodb works
- cURL POST to local ps + mLab mongodb works
- cURL    GET to local ps + local mongodb works

  ## However,
- cURL POST to Heroku ps + mLab mongodb **doesn't** work but instead results in `Cannot POST /parse` error.

Node file `index.js` is pointing to the correct heroku address of format `https://myApp.herokuapp.com/parse/`

Local cURL POST is adapted from [the migration guide](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App#verification):

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appID" \
    -H "X-Parse-Client-Key: clientKey" \
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: restKey" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
    http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

Local cURL GET:

```
curl -X GET \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appID" \
    -H "X-Parse-Client-Key: clientKey" \
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: restKey" \
    http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

Remote cURL POST :

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appID" \
    -H "X-Parse-Client-Key: clientKey" \
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: restKey" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
    https://myApp.herokuapp.com/parse/
```

Tried trouble shooting tips [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/651) but didn't get anywhere.
[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504293/parse-server-cloud-code-function-cannot-post) doesn't seem to help. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notice** how the remote cURL post doesn't end with the `classes` path designation. Use this as your remote POST target:

```
https://myApp.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/GameScore
```